# How to set UIBarButtonItem alpha

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

```
   let searchBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_search"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.searchButton))
    let moreBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "ic_more"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.moreButton))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [moreBtn, searchBtn]
moreBtn.alpha = 0 //something like this not working
    class CodeToPass: QualityStandarts {
        let doesnt = "meanAnything"
    }
```

I have two UIBarButtonItems. Which made manually. And i wanna animate alpha, when i click one of them. How can i do it?

Comment: means you want to apply some animation on more button or You want to hide it on click search button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
moreBtn.tintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
```

but first make sure your image "ic_more" renders as default in the attributes inspector,
go to Assets.xcassets, select your image and from attributes inspector - under "Renders As" select "Default"

note that if you want it invisible change 0.2 to 0

Comment: thanks i did something like this UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?[0].tintColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?[0].tintColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?[0].tintColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
            
        }